# Laravel- How to update all child when parent is changed?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

[I'm looking for best practice to handle]

I have data structure like below:

```
Category Class

protected $fillable = [
   'id', 'price', 'name'

];

public function products()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id');
}

Product Class 

protected $fillable = [
   'category_id', 'price' 
];

public function category
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
}
```

**Let's say I updated price at category. So, I want to update all price in product that related to this category table it will update same price as category as well.**

Comment: you need to add a "on cascade" update on the `migration` of the model

Comment: I prefer with `ON UPDATE CASCADE` on migration

Comment: Thank@sta and @Fabiotk For your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your example, if you want to use with the model relationship.

```
$categorid = 5;
$newprice = '500';

Category::find($categorid)->products()->update(['price'=>$newprice]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options, either use

```
$table->foreignId('category_id')
      ->constrained()
      ->onUpdate('cascade');
```

or if you can not change your db structure use [model observer](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers) to update it

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative Solution** : When you need to perform a **cascading update**, some indicate the use of static methods in the model. But, there is a simpler way and is not explicit in the documentation

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

Or, with constrained method (from Laravel 7) :

```
$table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade');
```

It will update the child records `category_id` when parent record `id` that change.

Answer (score 1):

```
$category = Category::where('id', 'category-id')->first();

$category->products()->update(['price' => $category->price]);
```